# FirebaseStorage: How to Delete Directories with prefix and limit of folders/files in Node?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage, bucket

Is there any option to remove sub-folders and files with prefix and limit as getting the error due to limited resources/memory during deleting with a simple prefix.

```
const removeFolderFromBucket = folderPath => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      return storage.bucket(bucketName).deleteFiles({ prefix: folderPath, force: true }, function(error) {
        if (error) {
          console.error(`Failed to remove folder: ${folderPath}. Error :${error}`);
          // reject(error);
        }
        resolve({ status: "ok", code: 200 });
      });
    }).catch(error => {
      console.error(`Failed to remove folder: ${folderPath} in promise catch. Error: `, error);
      // throw error;
    });
  };
```

So I can use the function in recursion with a limit with await/promise and no issues due to number of sub-folders and files having in a folder path (prefix).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the solution but don't know - Is it good and a better approach? Please see and suggest.

```
while (true) {
  const [files] = await storage
    .bucket(bucketName)
    .getFiles({ prefix: path, maxResults: 50 });
  const fileCount = files.length;
  for (const file of files) {
    await file.delete();
  }
  if (fileCount < 50) {
    break;
  }
}
```